# How to make a Whatsapp / Line / WeChat / Google Talk Clone?

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, openfire, whatsapp

I am new to stackoverflow. Now I have to task to build a instant messaging system that's use for a group of people in an office. Basically I need the client on phone and computers.

1. Android
2. IOS
3. Windows
4. maybe Mac OSX later

Some basic functions needed, like one-to-one chatting, group chatting, etc.
also transfer of photo, files...
basically just like whatsapp/line/wechat/google talk, etc.

I would like to know what I have to deploy and what kinds of technology that I should use.I am thinking to use Openfire XMPP server.

I have the following concern:

1.Is it secure? Can I use SSL or other encryption to ensure the conversation not to be stolen by others?
2.Is it expandable? That means can I have multiple servers at different location and all work together?
3.Can it support all platforms that I mentioned above? (android, ios, windows, mac)

I would also like to know what kind of library should I use to make the apps:

1. In android
2. In IOS
3. In windows
4. In Mac osx

Thanks all of you for the suggestions!

If there are other deployment ideas that's better than using openfire, please suggest! Thankyou!

Comment: best place to start is google. SO is not the place to ask people to do your work

Comment: YES, I did google and I found openfire looks very close to what I want but I just want to get some expert ideas. Thanks anyway

Comment: can you see my answer below? I hope it gives you some idea

Comment: It  is essential to know about the architecture of  WhatsApp, before commencing a clone app like WhatsApp. Kindly refer the below post. i hope this would help you to know about the technicalities of whatsapp.
http://blog.contus.com/how-whatsapp-works-technically-and-how-to-build-an-app-similar-to-it/

Comment: How you solved your problem? did you installed Openfire on remote server? Which client you are using for Android?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use like this(in my opinion):

1. you should have a server
2. you should use web service(.net mvc4.5)
3. you should have a strong and fast database(HP vertica or Oracle for me)
4. you can write `get`and `post` methods to `insert , update,delete,and get data from server`
5. and you should write ios,android,windows phone clients using your webserice to communicate each other .

this is one scenario,

Comment: I first plan to use MySQL, but I am not sure if it is fast enough or not. Should I use Oracle?

Comment: in my advice you can use more faster database, for example HP Vertica , it use pl/sql and it is close to oracle , and **in my opinion** it is very fast, and up to **1TB** it is totally free

Comment: I checked with HP Vertica and it seems to be a database all handled by HP? How about if I want to host a database myself? Is oracle a better option then HP?

Comment: Hp vertica is faster than oraacle as I know, and the express limitations are different. HP vertica is 1TB limit but oracle has 4GB and only 1 processesor and 1 GB Ram as I know, I think first of all you do not care of database because in the beginning you dont have very big data I think, if you have a big data in the future, this means you have big customer and you have much money :) and you get any db as your need.